# How to deploy 3rd party jars in maven root repository?

Tags: java, jar, maven-3

I have a jar file I want to upload that jar to the central maven repository for my further use. I am tried [this-link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) and It run successfully but as I told you above now I want to upload this jar to the central for further use and I am trying to use [this-link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html). But I am not understanding it properly. I need a brief tutorial that what is

> DRepositoryId and Durl

and how can I get DRepositoryId and Durl.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to upload your jar file to maven central, you need to follow these instructions: https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html